# Can you create a Finite State Machine using SOLID principles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface, state-machine

I'm currently studying game development and for one of our projects, we had to create a finite state machine that would function as a simple AI. It has always been encouraged to make your code with SOLID principles but for this project I couldn't think of a way to do it. Although it wasn't required for this project I would still like to find a way to do it. It's made in Unity c#.

```
public interface IState
{
    public IState CheckForState();
}

public class Walk : IState
{
    float speed = 10;

    public IState CheckForState()
    {
        if (speed > 5)
        {
            return Run;
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

To make it SOLID you would have to find a way to remove 'Run' from the function cause if the 'Run' script is removed the function wouldn't work anymore, but it should still be able to get it if available.

Comment: maybe you can elaborate on why you think this implmenetation breaks with SOLID? What exactly is `Run` and where is it defined?

Comment: First thought, a higher controller that knows about run state should tell walk state what to change to if speed is slower or higher... Not sure though how you use it.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I believe it breaks SOLID cause the `Walk` script would break if the `Run` script were to be removed, the `Walk` script is dependent on its existence and would therefore break the dependency inversion principle, as far as I'm aware. `Run` is a state the AI could be in.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple solutions that come to mind that would allow for a fully SOLID solution.

### Solution 1

The first and simplest to suffice the dependency inversion principle is to inject the `Run` class into the `Walk` class, like so:

```cs
public class Walk : IState
{
    float speed = 10;
    private readonly IState _runState;
    public Walk(IState runState)
    {
        _runState = runState;
    }

    public IState CheckForState()
    {
        if (speed > 5)
        {
            return _runState;
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

This solution makes it so `Walk` is no longer dependent on a concrete implementation of Run, but still allows it to transition to a run state. However, this does require that `Walk` knows which states it can transition to (which I think is a reasonable expectation).

### Solution 2

You can further decouple this by representing the state transitions as objects. This would look something like this:

```cs
public interface IState
{
    public IState CheckForState();
    public float Value {get;}
}

public interface IStateTransition
{
    public IState CheckTransition(IState source);
}

public class GreaterThanTransition : IStateTransition
{
    private readonly IState _targetState;
    private readonly int _checkValue;

    public GreaterThanTransition(IState targetState, int checkValue)
    {
        _targetState = targetState;
        _checkValue = checkValue;
    }
    public IState CheckTransition(IState sourceState) => sourceState.Value > _checkValue ? _targetState : sourceState;
}

public class Walk : IState
{
    private readonly List<IStateTransition> _transitions;

    public Walk(List<IStateTransition> transitions)
    {
        _transitions = transitions;
    }
    public float Value => 10;

    public IState CheckForState() => _transitions.Select(t => t.CheckTransition(this)).FirstOrDefault(s => s != this) ?? this;
}
```

Then you can create a Walk instance like this:

```cs
new Walk(new List<IStateTransition>
{
    new GreaterThanTransition(new Run(...), 5)
});
```

This requires that a value from the state object can be used in the `IStateTransition` to check if a state transition needs to occur. I used an `int` in my example as the type of the `Value` property, but you could easily switch it to be a generic type.

This solution completely decouples each state and captures the state transitions as reusable components. It is more complex in some regards since the code is now split across more classes and interfaces, but it also fully incorporates the SOLID principles.